# if div is empty, hide a different div element

Tags: jquery, hide, element, parent, closest

I have a blog posts page with "read more/read less" toggle button for each post.

I would like to hide "a.wpex-link" if ".wpex_div p" is empty. The problem is that needs to select its parent/closest link since all posts have the same class.

```
<a onclick="wpex_toggle(548787318, 'Read more', 'Read less'); return false;" class="wpex-link" href="#" target="_blank">Read less</a>
<div class="wpex_div" id="wpex548787318" style="display: block;">
    <div class="sidebar-content"></div>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem. If you found an answer helpful, you should mark it as accepted to guide future readers of this post. you can mark an answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.wpex_div:has(p:empty)').prev('.wpex-link').hide();
```

```js
$('.wpex_div:has(p:empty)').prev('.wpex-link').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="wpex_toggle(548787318, 'Read more', 'Read less'); return false;" class="wpex-link" href="#" target="_blank">Read less</a>
<div class="wpex_div" id="wpex548787318" style="display: block;">
    <div class="sidebar-content">The p element is empty. That is why the 'Read less' anchor is not displaying</div>
    <p></p>
</div>
```